# How to deploy/run/submit Spark scala jars to HDInsight Azure cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, azure-hdinsight, ambari

I want to create an on-demand cluster and submit spark-scala jars to that cluster and terminate the same once done. It is quite simple in AWS using command-runner.jar
How do I achieve that for Azure HDInsight?

I don't want anything manual or via the Azure UI.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement a few months ago and made the following PowerShell script which calls PuTTY to upload the JAR and a configuration file and then sends the spark-submit command.

```
cls

$PuttyBasePath = "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\"
$PlinkPath = $PuttyBasePath + "plink.exe"
$PscpPath = $PuttyBasePath + "pscp.exe"

$SshHost = "someCluster-ssh.azurehdinsight.net"
$SshUserName = "sshuser"
$SshPassword = "somePassword"

$MainPath = "/home/sshuser/"
$BaseDirectoryToUploadFiles = "/home/sshuser/testPath"
$DirectoryToUploadFiles = $BaseDirectoryToUploadFiles + "20180505235534"

# Files to load
$ConfigFilePath = "C:\config.json"
$JarFilePath = "C:\somejar.jar"    

function UploadFiles 
{     
    &$PlinkPath -v -pw $SshPassword $SshUserName@$SshHost mkdir -p $DirectoryToUploadFiles

    $FilesToUpload = @($JarFilePath, $ConfigFilePath)

    foreach ($FileToUpload in $FilesToUpload) 
    {   
        &$PscpPath -v -pw $SshPassword -r $FileToUpload $SshUserName@${SshHost}:$DirectoryToUploadFiles
    }
}


function RunSparkJob
{
    cls

    echo y | &$PlinkPath -v -pw $SshPassword $SshUserName@$SshHost ("/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/bin/spark-submit" + 
    " --master yarn" +
    " --deploy-mode cluster" +
    " --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=8" +
    " --conf spark.yarn.am.attemptFailuresValidityInterval=1h" +
    " --conf spark.yarn.max.executor.failures=240" +
    " --conf spark.yarn.executor.failuresValidityInterval=1h" +
    " --conf spark.task.maxFailures=4" +
    " --conf spark.speculation=true" +
    " --conf spark.speculation.multiplier=40" + 
    " --conf spark.speculation.quantile=0.85" +
    " --num-executors 30" +
    " --executor-cores 10" +
    " --files ${DirectoryToUploadFiles}/config.json" +
    " --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.11:2.2.0,com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11:2.2.0" +
    " --class com.test.someClass ${DirectoryToUploadFiles}/somejar.jar")
}

UploadFiles
RunSparkJob
```